# How make default value in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to create a default color when I add a new event.

Now the color is set to NULL.

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult SaveEvent(Event e)
{
        var status = false;

        if (e.EventID > 0)
        {
            //Update the event
            var v = db.Events.Where(a => a.EventID == e.EventID).FirstOrDefault();
            if (v != null) 
            {
                v.EventTitle = e.EventTitle;

                v.EventDescription = e.EventDescription;
                v.ThemeColor = e.ThemeColor;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            db.Events.Add(e);
        }

        db.SaveChanges();
        status = true;

        return new JsonResult { Data = new { status = status } };
    }
```

How make `ThemeColor` red when I add the event ?

```
                public partial class Event
{
    public int EventID { get; set; }
    public string EventTitle { get; set; }
    public string EventDescription { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> StartDate { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> EndDate { get; set; }
    public string ThemeColor { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Add the Event class to the question

Comment: public string ThemeColor { get; set; }

Comment: you can override getter and setter: private string _themeColor; 
public string ThemeColor{  get => string.IsNullOrEmpty(_themeColor) ? "Red" : _themeColor; set => _themeColor = value;}

Answer (score 1):

If you use c# 6 or higher, you can use this syntax to set the default value to a property

```
public string ThemeColor { get; set; } = "Red";
```

Otherwise you can initialize via constructor.

But if you are explicitly sending the ThemeColor as null in the payload, when invoking the method then you'll need to manually check if ThemeColor is null and set it in the controller

For example:

```
v.ThemeColor = e.ThemeColor ?? "Red";
```

EDIT:

You can add the null check on top of the method and with that you'll cover both cases

```
if(e.ThemeColor == null)
{
    e.ThemeColor = "Red";
}
```

Comment: thank you but your solutions not work for me when i add a new event make me color is NULL and not red color

Comment: You went with the second example, with checking yourself in the code?